# Validate password if it is numeric and has more than 6 digits in Java

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and I am working on a To do list Android app. Therefore, I need a password validation which validates the password, if it is numeric and if it has more than 6 digits. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Use Regex `^[0-9]{6,}$` Like, `String regex = "^[0-9]{6,}$";`    `password.matches(regex);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String password = getPassword(); // however you get the password
boolean valid = StringUtils.isNumeric(password) && password.length() > 6;
```

Comment: Better way is to use regex.

Comment: That's debatable, @Jags. Better why? Because performance? The question states that this is an Android to-do list app -- not a password validator app that needs to check a high volume of passwords. Given this information, performance of the password validation code is probably of a secondary priority to readability and simplicity.

Comment: Regex "\\d{6}" is much more readable and simple. Also, its built in java and code doesn't have to depends on third party library (StringUtils in this case). On top, if you have two solution available, one having better performance then other, i would go with better one always. But agree with you - its debatable and individual's preference as far as readability is concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this function could help you :

```
public static boolean check(String passwd)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(passwd);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  } 
  return passwd.length()>6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! That saved my day.

Comment: is there a problem in my function ? :(

Comment: That's a rather poor way to detect numeric. Not only is looking for an exception dubious, you'll accept passwords like this: `-1.23e-23` which is surely not what is intended. And what about locale?

Comment: What's your problem with me man , you're following me in every page , i'm here to help him , i gave him a function and it's working , i'm not a genius to give the perfect answer , but i'm trying to , is your job here to bother others , why you dislike his question , he have a problem and he find a solution does that bother you :/

Comment: No problem with you. I stated clear reasons for my criticism. I also improved your code.

Answer (score 0):

If check needs to happen a lot then more better solution is to use pre-compiled regex rather then length checks.

```
package regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestReg {

    static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}");

    static public boolean isValid(String passwd){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(passwd);
        return m.matches();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123456";
        System.out.println(s+"->"+isValid(s));
        s = "12345";
        System.out.println(s+"->"+isValid(s));
        s = "1a2345";
        System.out.println(s+"->"+isValid(s));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123456->true
12345->false
1a2345->false
```

**Update**

Performance of regex depends on underlying engine used. In pure java 7 world, if you strings are small then character array outperforms regex. See also http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/string-performance-exact-string.html

Simple test I did

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class TestReg {

    static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}");

    static public boolean isValid(String passwd){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(passwd);
        return m.matches();
    }

    static public boolean isValidTraditional(String passwd) {
        return StringUtils.isNumeric(passwd) && passwd.length() > 6;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start, end;
        boolean valid = false;
        String[] values = {"123456","12345","1a23456", "12345a" };

        //warm up
        isValid(values[0]);
        //end warm up

        for(String s:values){

            start = System.nanoTime();
            valid = isValid(s);
            end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("[Regex]  "+s+"->"+valid+"\t"+(end-start));

            start = System.nanoTime();
            valid = isValidTraditional(s);
            end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("[Simple] "+s+"->"+valid+"\t"+(end-start));

        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Regex]  123456->true   7699
[Simple] 123456->false  16160884
[Regex]  12345->false   9410
[Simple] 12345->false   2566
[Regex]  1a23456->false 4706
[Simple] 1a23456->false 1711
[Regex]  12345a->false  5988
[Simple] 12345a->false  2566
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks ! Any specific suggestion I should put/edit my answer? I thought its self explanatory.

Comment: In what sense is regex better? And better than what.  I don't think it is. Convince me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I see.. you are right. If String is small and comparison string is small then char array is much faster than regex. I did some run on my local. Will update my post.